# Outlook 2007- Names in “From” field empty

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I read the article "Outlook 2010 - Names in “From” field empty" (http://adminsgoodies.com/outlook-2010-names-in-from-field-empty/) and have a similar but not identical question.
I have an empty from field for messages I have sent. This only started to happen yesterday. It only occurs when I reply to or forward a message from a folder, where my outlook settings store replies in the same folder.
If I drag the message to the sent folder my name appears in the from field. When I drag it back to the original folder my name is still present.
Any idea whats causing this?
.. and any ideas on the fix please?!

Comment: Could you link that article, please?

Comment: done, apologies for the schoolboy omission